# XNA - Reading Directly from Speaker Output on Windows

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I was wondering if it is possible to read speaker output from XNA. For instance, if the user plays a song via Spotify or Youtube, the application can read the output stream and get the spectrum data.  My platform is Windows.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Yes, my platform is on the PC. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, these days it depends on the sound card/driver.  If the "stereo mix" pin (as it is typically, but not always, named) is available for recording from, then yes.  If not, no.

The only way around that is to use a loopback sound driver.

Comment: Is it possible to read the volume level or other interfaces such as if a CD drive is spinning?

Comment: You can do this from any available recording interfaces.  However, when you record from CD audio, this is not normally hooked up anymore.  The audio CDs are read and played back digitally via software now, rather than through the CD-ROM drive's own audio output.